# Separate Key Value From LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I need the key and value data from SharedToDomains and SharedFromDomains. I want to print the values.

```
var LogResponse = DeserializeFromJson<AttributeContainer>(sLogResponse);

public class AttributeContainer
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> MimeTypes { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Domain> SharedToDomains { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Domain> SharedFromDomains { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: having Json arrays, i want like this  LogResponse.SharedFromDomains["Value"].Documents,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way:

```
 foreach( var s in SharedToDomains.Keys )
 {
       string key = s;
       string val = SharedToDomains[s].ToString();
 }
```

If you really want to use linq:

```
var outputList = from s in SharedToDomains select new { key=s.Key, value=s.Value };
```

Comment: Updated that for you.

Comment: i am using this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497054/deserialize-json-using-json-net i want result to fetch the datas

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497054/deserialize-json-using-json-net i am using this code , i want result for that to fetch the values.

Answer (score 2):

```
SharedToDomains.Select(x => x.Value).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: if you need key also use `SharedToDomains.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Key + "|" + x.Value));`

Comment: hi iwant Add key values in  sb.Append("{");
            sb.AppendFormat(@"""DT_RowId"": ""{0}""", 1);
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.AppendFormat(@"""DT_RowClass"": ""{0}""", rowClass);
            sb.Append(",");            
            sb.AppendFormat(@"""0"": ""{0}""", "<div style='text-align:center;' class='Italictxt'>" + key + "</div>");
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.AppendFormat(@"""1"": ""{0}""", "<div style='text-align:center;' class='Italictxt'>" +  key + "</div>");                                    
            sb.Append("},");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497054/deserialize-json-using-json-net i am using this code , i want result for that to fetch the values.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the value collection of the Dictionary and print the domain to the screen. I've put it in a method so you can re-use it later on:

```
private void PrintValues(Dictionary<string, Domain> dict)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Domain> kvp in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key); //Key
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value.ToString()); //Value
    }
}

//Usage:
PrintValues(SharedToDomains);
PrintValues(SharedFromDomains);
```

Comment: A method for this is a bit overkill, as is the use of KeyValuePair.

Comment: I first used a loop over the ValueCollection but then saw on your answer that he also wants the Key. That's why I changed it. And if you're going to use the same code more than once, a method is always a good idea. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497054/deserialize-json-using-json-net i am using this code , i want result for that to fetch the values.